# run cgi script using nginx

Tags: nginx, cgi

I am trying to execute cgi script on Nginx. In nginx.conf file, I added a location directive such as below:

```
location /cgi-bin{
    root cgi-bin;
    index index.cgi;
}
```

When I try to connect to http://example.com/cgi-bin/index.cgi,  it says file not found.  In error.log, I see the request as "http://example.com/html/cgi-bin/index.cgi.
cgi-bin is not in html folder.  The correct path is "http://example.com/cgi-bin/index.cgi

I tried many possibilities for location directive.  Either it looks in html/cgi-bin or it does /cgi-bin/cgi-bin/index.cgi.  I am not sure why it uses 'cgi-bin' twice

Any suggestions.. I have been trying for hours now!!!

Comment: What is the correct _path_ on the filesystem to the `index.cgi` ? And by the way I guess it's better to ask this question on superuser.com

Comment: Nginx cannot run cgi scripts by design. There are workarounds, e.g. http://wiki.nginx.org/SimpleCGI